# CASE command in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I need your help. I have written some codes in SQL and I have some problems with CASE commands. I want to output 1 for grades > 90, 2 for grades > 80, 3 for grades > 70, and 4 otherwise. After I check my code carefully, I still can not fix it. All records in table have 4 value ( in ELSE command). Please help me. Thank you very much !

```
CREATE TABLE student_grades 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    number_grade INTEGER,
    fraction_completed REAL
);

INSERT INTO student_grades (name, number_grade, fraction_completed)
    VALUES ("Winston", 90, 0.805);
INSERT INTO student_grades (name, number_grade, fraction_completed)
    VALUES ("Winnefer", 95, 0.901);
INSERT INTO student_grades (name, number_grade, fraction_completed)
    VALUES ("Winsteen", 85, 0.906);
INSERT INTO student_grades (name, number_grade, fraction_completed)
    VALUES ("Wincifer", 66, 0.7054);
INSERT INTO student_grades (name, number_grade, fraction_completed)
    VALUES ("Winster", 76, 0.5013);
INSERT INTO student_grades (name, number_grade, fraction_completed)
    VALUES ("Winstonia", 82, 0.9045);

SELECT 
    name, number_grade, 
    ROUND(fraction_completed * 100,0) "percent_completed" 
FROM
    student_grades;

SELECT 
    number_grade 
FROM
    student_grades 
ORDER BY
    number_grade DESC;

SELECT 
    name, number_grade, 
    CASE number_grade
       WHEN number_grade >= 90 THEN 1 
       WHEN number_grade >= 80 THEN 2 
       WHEN number_grade >= 70 THEN 3 
       ELSE 4
    END AS "letter_grade"
FROM 
    student_grades
ORDER BY
    number_grade DESC;
```

The result is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGokV.png)

Comment: SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be4211/1

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Looks like MySQL, but can't say it for sure.

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing up the two different ways to use `CASE`.

One way is:

```
CASE columnname
    WHEN value1 THEN result1
    WHEN value2 THEN result2
    ...
END
```

The other is:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    ...
END
```

If you're testing a condition, you shouldn't have a column name after `CASE`, because the first form is actually just short for:

```
CASE
    WHEN columnname = value1 THEN result1
    WHEN columnname = value2 THEN result2
    ...
END
```

So your code is equivalent to:

```
CASE
    WHEN number_grade = number_grade >= 90 THEN 1
    WHEN number_grade = number_grade >= 80 THEN 2
    WHEN number_grade = number_grade >= 70 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

The correct syntax is:

```
CASE
    WHEN number_grade >= 90 THEN 1 
    WHEN number_grade >= 80 THEN 2 
    WHEN number_grade >= 70 THEN 3 
    ELSE 4
END as "letter_grade"
```

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `number_grade` after `CASE`. Try to delete `number_grade`, so your code will be:

```
CASE
   WHEN number_grade >= 90 THEN 1 
   WHEN number_grade >= 80 THEN 2 
   WHEN number_grade >= 70 THEN 3 
   ELSE 4
```

Comment: This adds nothing, compared to the other answer, which was posted 4 minutes before.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you very much!

Comment: I made this myself b4 reading others. im using handphone to answer. so please t o consider to accept it. thanks